# i have problem with fetching data array in laravel inside controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, controller, fetch

i have problem with fetching data after using ajax how can i fetch data and pass it to another array when i pass one field using ->value() its working but i want to pass multiple data . any help please !

**code:**

```
public function GetCoursId(Request $request)
    {

/*
        $idcours = $request->input('idcours');
        $fcours = DB::table('cours')->where('id_cours', $idcours)->value('field_cours') ; 
        $idmod = DB::table('cours')->where('id_cours', $idcours)->value('id_module') ;  */


        $output = array(
            'field_cours'  =>  $fcours,
            'id_module'    =>  $idmod,
            'idcours'    =>  $idcours 
        );
        echo json_encode($output); */

        $idcours = $request->input('idcours');
        $PerCours = DB::table('cours')->where('id_cours', $idcours)->get() ; 


        $output = array(
            'field_cours'  =>  $PerCours->field_cours,
            'id_module'    =>  $PerCours->id_module,
            'idcours'    =>  $idcours 
        ); 
        echo json_encode($output);    
    }    
}
```

Comment: your `PerCours` is  a collection and you need to iterate it. `$PerCours->field_cours` won't work without looping.

Comment: try `echo json_encode($PerCours);` because `$PerCourse` is the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it seems you have only one item in your collection and you want to get data from it. So use `first()` instead of `get()`

```
$idcours = $request->input('idcours');
$PerCours = DB::table('cours')->where('id_cours', $idcours)->first() ; 


    $output = array(
        'field_cours'  =>  $PerCours->field_cours,
        'id_module'    =>  $PerCours->id_module,
        'idcours'    =>  $idcours 
    ); 
echo json_encode($output);
```

You will able to get data now like

```
console.log(data.field_cours);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code like this:

```
public function GetCoursId(Request $request)
{
    $idcours = $request->input('idcours');
    $PerCours = DB::table('cours')->where('id_cours', $idcours)->get() ; 

    foreach($PerCours as $PerCour) {
        $field_cours[] = $PerCour['field_cours'];
        $id_module[] = $PerCour['id_module'];
    }
    $output = array(
        'field_cours'  =>  $field_cours,
        'id_module'    =>  $id_module,
        'idcours'    =>  $idcours 
    ); 
    echo json_encode($output);       
}
```

Comment: Could you further explain why this solution would solve the problem? Just providing a solution doesn't really help understand the why it works.

Answer (score -1):

its working when i pass echo json_encode($PerCours);

console.log(data['0'].field_cours) ;

there is a way to display directly : 
console.log(data.field_cours) ;